# PHP extract text from string - trim?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have the following XML:

```
<id>tag:search.twitter.com,2005:22204349686</id>
```

How can i write everything after the second colon to a variable?

E.g. `22204349686`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$var = preg_replace('/^([^:]+:){2}/', '', 'tag:search.twitter.com,2005:22204349686');`

I am assuming you already have the string without the `<id>` bits.

Otherwise, for SimpleXML:
`$var = preg_replace('/^([^:]+:){2}/', '', "{$yourXml->id}");`

Answer (score 3):

```
if(preg_match('#<id>.*?:.*?:(.*?)</id>#',$input,$m)) {
 $num = $m[1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you already have just the tags content in a variable `$str`, you could use [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) to get everything from the second `:` on:

```
list(,,$rest) = explode(':', $str, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have in a variable (`$str`) the content of *id* tag.

```
// get last occurence of colon
$pos = strrpos($str, ":");

if ($pos !== false) {
  // get substring of $str from position $pos to the end of $str 
  $result = substr($str, $pos); 
} else {
  $result = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode` and `strip_tags`:

```
list(,,$id) = explode( ':', strip_tags( $input ), 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

First, parse the XML with an XML parser.  Find the text content of the node in question (`tag:search.twitter.com,2005:22204349686`).  Then, write a relevant regex, e.g.

```
<?php
$str = 'tag:search.twitter.com,2005:22204349686';
preg_match('#^([^:]+):([^,]+),([0-9]+):([0-9]+)#', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex seems to me inappropriate for such a simple matching.

If you dont have the ID tags around the string, you can simply do

```
echo trim(strrchr($xml, ':'), ':');
```

If they are around, you can use

```
$xml = '<id>tag:search.twitter.com,2005:22204349686</id>';
echo filter_var(strrchr($xml, ':'), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
// 22204349686
```

The [`strrchr`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php) part returns `:22204349686</id>` and the [`filter_var`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) part strips everything that's not a number.

Answer (score -2):

```
function between($t1,$t2,$page) {
    $p1=stripos($page,$t1);
    if($p1!==false) {
        $p2=stripos($page,$t2,$p1+strlen($t1));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return substr($page,$p1+strlen($t1),$p2-$p1-strlen($t1));
}

$x='<id>tag:search.twitter.com,2005:22204349686</id>';
$text=between(',','<',$x);
if($text!==false) {
   //got some text..
}
```